# Deploy shopify (Remix) app on fly.io server

Tags: postgresql, docker, shopify-app, remix.run, fly

I have created a Shopify application using [shopify-app-remix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/shopify-app-remix) package, which is mentioned in the official documentation of Shopify. Now I want to deploy this application on the server. I used [fly.io](https://fly.io/), which is also mentioned in the Shopify documentation. For my Shopify app, I used [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) with a [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/) database. I have also created a postgrace database on fly.io with the help of [this](https://fly.io/docs/postgres/getting-started/create-pg-cluster/) documentation and attached it to my application. My app is successfully built and deployed on fly.io but is not running. It is constantly loading.  I have mentioned the fly.io machine logs below. And also attached my `fly.toml` file as a [screenshot](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/45869851?key=eeab60df4b37e6332c3999806df30bf9). Can someone please see my issue?

````
2024-02-07T12:05:32.344 app[148ed727f93de8] den [info] INFO Preparing to run: `docker-entrypoint.sh node` as root

2024-02-07T12:05:32.353 app[148ed727f93de8] den [info] INFO [fly api proxy] listening at /.fly/api

2024-02-07T12:05:32.355 app[148ed727f93de8] den [info] 2024/02/07 12:05:32 listening on [fdaa:6:b09:a7b:15c:8976:9a82:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)

2024-02-07T12:05:32.442 runner[148ed727f93de8] den [info] Machine started in 595ms

2024-02-07T12:05:33.354 app[148ed727f93de8] den [info] INFO Main child exited normally with code: 0

2024-02-07T12:05:33.354 app[148ed727f93de8] den [info] INFO Starting clean up.

2024-02-07T12:05:33.355 app[148ed727f93de8] den [info] WARN hallpass exited, pid: 316, status: signal: 15 (SIGTERM)

2024-02-07T12:05:33.360 app[148ed727f93de8] den [info] 2024/02/07 12:05:33 listening on [fdaa:6:b09:a7b:15c:8976:9a82:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)

2024-02-07T12:05:33.445 proxy[148ed727f93de8] den [info] machine started in 1.602390375s

2024-02-07T12:05:34.355 app[148ed727f93de8] den [info] [ 2.363003] reboot: Restarting system

2024-02-07T12:05:34.520 runner[148ed727f93de8] den [info] machine exited with exit code 0, not restarting

2024-02-07T12:05:40.864 proxy[148ed727f93de8] den [info] waiting for machine to be reachable on 0.0.0.0:8081 (waited 7.418556817s so far)

2024-02-07T12:05:46.867 proxy[148ed727f93de8] den [info] waiting for machine to be reachable on 0.0.0.0:8081 (waited 13.421951594s so far)

2024-02-07T12:05:52.805 proxy[148ed727f93de8] den [info] waiting for machine to be reachable on 0.0.0.0:8081 (waited 19.36011226s so far)

2024-02-07T12:05:57.808 proxy[148ed727f93de8] den [error] failed to connect to machine: gave up after 15 attempts (in 24.362882318s)

2024-02-07T12:05:58.064 proxy[e2865373c17658] den [info] Starting machine

2024-02-07T12:05:58.259 app[e2865373c17658] den [info] [ 0.057848] PCI: Fatal: No config space access function found

2024-02-07T12:05:58.477 app[e2865373c17658] den [info] INFO Starting init (commit: bfa79be)...

2024-02-07T12:05:58.548 app[e2865373c17658] den [info] INFO Preparing to run: `docker-entrypoint.sh node` as root

2024-02-07T12:05:58.557 app[e2865373c17658] den [info] INFO [fly api proxy] listening at /.fly/api

2024-02-07T12:05:58.560 app[e2865373c17658] den [info] 2024/02/07 12:05:58 listening on [fdaa:6:b09:a7b:15c:54aa:4c7e:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)```
````

Comment: I am not able to run the app with the fly.io Postgres database. To run the app I have hosted it on fly.io and for the database, I have chosen [supabase](https://supabase.com/).

Comment: Did you set the shopify.web.toml port? and did you set the fly.toml? They need to match on the port.  The error says it's unable to connect to the machine, so it can be that the port is not matching.